# How to get the Australian financial year from a date in a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, date, datetime

I have a pandas dataframe that has a datetime column called `date`.
How can I create a new column to represent the **Australian** financial year using the `date` column?

The Australian financial year starts on 1 July and ends the next year on 30 June.

- Example 1: 10 June 2019 is FY 2019
- Example 2: 5 July 2019 is FY 2020

Answer (score 0):

The code below creates a new column representing **Australian** financial year using the existing 'date' column:

```
df['FY'] = df['date'].map(lambda d: d.year + 1 if d.month > 6 else d.year)
```